# Inserting img in a div using another div's background image as a src in JS

Tags: javascript

there. How can I change my JS code in order to have  only one image in my hidden_div? Here is my code.

Best regards.

```
<a href="#"><div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-ima ge:url('css/images1/img/img1.jpg');background-size:100% 100%;")></div></a>
<a href="#"><div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img2.jpg');background-size:100% 100%;")></div></a>
<a href="#"><div onClick="show(this);" class="img" style="background-image:url('css/images1/img/img3.jpg');background-size:100% 100%;")></div></a>

<div id="hidden_div"></div>
<script>
function show(element) {
          var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden_div");

          var imgElement = document.createElement("IMG"); 

          imgElement.src=element.style.backgroundImage.replace('url(','').replace(')','');
          hidden.appendChild(imgElement);
          };
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you guys, very much, highly appeciated . :)

Comment: The accepted answer does not work cross browser though.

Comment: It works on my browser.

Comment: Okay, if you're the only one looking at it then it shouldn't matter. I'd choose the better code myself though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make a small change in your script as follows

```
function show(element) {

    var hidden = document.getElementById("hidden_div"); 
    var imgURL = element.style.backgroundImage.replace('url(','').replace(')','');    
    var imgElement = "<img src='"+ imgURL +"' /> 
    hidden.innerHTML  = imgElement;

 };
```

Comment: You know your code doesn't run on Mozila firefox, the browser shows empty img icon.

Comment: Hi dear , make a change as follows         var imgElement = "<img src="+ imgURL +" /> ..  remove the double quotes in src=  part of code. i checked in firfox and chrome , it works now

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very much what do you want, if you can explain to me, please.. But, I think inside of every 'div', in the 'style', there's a extra ) at the end.

Comment: I have already solved the problem, thank you for your attention, ye, you are right, thereis an extra Comma in my code, i already  corrected it.:)